# Transfer speed systematic variance

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I've been trying to copy a one single large file from my internal HDD to a USB drive.

There's something strange I found:

[image: Speed Variance]

The speed kept constant to 5 MB/s and then at regular intervals went down to 2.70 MB/s.

Can someone please explain why such a thing happens?